# I need to list the only latest versions of the products with php - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I'm just trying to list the only latest versions of the products. Not all versions with the same product name.

So this:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

***tables are not so important I just want the code to get the data.**
***tables are not so important I just want the code to get the data.**

This is my code but lists nothing :

```
include("databaseinfo.php");
$sql = "SELECT product_name,release_date,version FROM product GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY product_ID DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($b=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $b['product_name']." ".$b['release_date']." ".$b['version'];
}
```

My product table:

[image]

Comment: Try with `DISTINCT` in Select like `select DISTINCT(product_name),....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select product_name, release_date, version
from product p
where release_date = (
    select max(p1.release_date)
    from product p1
    where p1.product_id = p.product_id
)
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use `rank()`:

```
select product_name, release_date, version
from (
    select p.*, rank() over(partition by product_id order by release_date desc)
    from product
) t
where rn = 1
```

This assumes that `product_id` uniquely identifies each product (so your table would have several rows per `product_id`) - if that's not the case, use `product_name` instead.